# Difference between Caching object and Hash map

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was reading an article on Caching object in asp.net framework and I was looking on the class behavior. It has a HashMap like structure and looks like that I can actually instantiate a Hashmap and use it as collection.

What extra benefit does cache object bring over hashmap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, I assume you mean a `System.Collections.Hashtable` when you talk about HashMap.

The difference between cache object and a simple Hashtable is that it provides you additional services. For instance, you can set object expiration rules on the Cache object. Also, you can define the size quota of the cache. Hence, you may say that no more than 100MB are cached. It's not so easy to implement using simple hashtables.

To find out more about Asp.Net caching, it might be worth checking out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998549.aspx#scalenetchapt06_topic14

Answer (score 5):

Caches usually invalidate their data according to certain rules (time since creation, time since last access, number of entries, space, etc) - or a cache could even be a "computing" cache which will fetch values for you if they're previously unknown.

Answer (score 1):

To complete previous answers, you can have a look at articles (like [this wikipedia one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms)) that describe the most frequently used cache strategies like LRU (Least Recently Used), MRU (Most Recently Used) etc.